# Rails join two tables or replace numbers by the words

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I want to write logs to the database and I have often repeated words (syslog, sms, voice, email), I need to instead these words insert numbers (syslog - 1, sms - 2, voice - 3, email - 4), so as not to clog the base repeating words. And then select the words instead numbers

Excuse me, i asked the question wrong. I have data already saved, and i need select it to my index.html.erb. query must be like this: "SELECT triggerid, severity, status, types.name FROM logs, types WHERE logs.type_id = types.id;" logs.type_id = (1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1), types.name = (email, sms, syslog, voice), types.id = (1, 2, 3, 4,) after query myst be: types.name = (email, sms, syslog, syslog, sms, sms, email). How can i use activerecord fo this result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what field name/table your wanting to store these numbers in so I'm going to just call it 'FIELD_NAME' and 'TABLE'.  Keeping it in mysql you could do this:

Retrieve:

```
  SELECT TABLE.*, case FIELD_NAME WHEN 'syslog' THEN 1 WHEN 'sms' THEN 2 WHEN 'voice' THEN 3 WHEN 'email' THEN 4 ELSE null END as FIELD_ALIAS FROM TABLE
```

the result will have an attribute of FIELD_NAME with the int value, and an attribute of FIELD_ALIAS with the text version.

Inserting (STR_VALUE is the string version of the field):

```
  INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME (FIELD_NAME) VALUES (case STR_VALUE WHEN 'syslog' THEN 1 WHEN 'sms' THEN 2 WHEN 'voice' THEN 3 WHEN 'email' THEN 4 ELSE null END)
```

I believe a better alternative though would be to offload this to your model.  for simplicity I'm going to refer to your integer version as 'int_value'.

```
  class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
    before_save :convert_int_value

    def str_value
      case self.int_value
      WHEN 1 THEN 'syslog'
      WHEN 2 THEN 'sms'
      WHEN 3 THEN 'voice'
      WHEN 4 THEN 'email'
    end

    protected
      def convert_int_value
        return nil unless int_value.is_a?(String)
        self.int_value = case self.int_value
        WHEN 'syslog' THEN 1
        WHEN 'sms' THEN 2
        WHEN 'voice' THEN 3
        WHEN 'email' THEN 4
      end
  end
```

Anytime you want the int version, just call int_value on your model.  If you want the string call str_value.  Additionally you can store the string version, in your int_value and before the record is saved it will convert it for you.  This way all you have to pass mysql is an integer.

---

Update per comment

If your associations are set up correctly (Log belongs_to :type)

```
  Log.includes(:type).each do |l|
    l.status
    l.type.name #> email, sms, or syslog
  end
```

I realized after the fact there is another solution as well, I think this is more what you were looking for

```
  Log.joins(:type).select('triggerid, severity, status, types.name')
```

Alt1

```
  Log.joins(:type).select('log.*, types.name')
```

Alt2

```
  Log.joins('JOINS types ON types.id = logs.type_id').select('log.*, types.name')
```

Comment: excuse me, i asked the question wrong, i have data already saved, i need to select it in tomy index.html.erb.

Comment: Excuse me, i asked the question wrong. I have data already saved, and i need select it to my index.html.erb.
query must be like this: "SELECT triggerid, severity, status, types.name FROM logs, types WHERE logs.type_id = types.id;"
logs.type_id = (1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1), types.name = (email, sms, syslog, voice), types.id = (1, 2, 3, 4,)
after query myst be: type.name = (email, sms, syslog, syslog, sms, sms, email).
How can i use activerecord fo this result?

Comment: Didn't want to put the code into a comment, look at the end of my answer again I appended it to the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

are you after one address per client?:

`Client.joins(:addresses)`

or every address with client info?:

`Adress.join(:client)`

Comment: `join` should be `joins`

Comment: generally I want to write logs to the database and I have often repeated words (syslog, sms, voice, email),
I need to instead these words insert numbers (syslog - 1, sms - 2, voice - 3, email - 4),
 so as not to clog the base repeating words. And then select the words instead numbers.